# Moodle.sty does not include multiple QUIZ

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle.sty including in a single .TEX file a few quiz environments. In the pdf appear all the quiz, but in the .XML only the last one. Someone can help me ?

```
\begin{quiz}{Q1}
\begin{multi}[points=1,multiple]{Q01}
\item* a
\item b
\end{multi}
\begin{multi}[points=1,multiple]{Q02}
\item* a
\item b
\end{multi}
\end{quiz}

\begin{quiz}{Q2}
\begin{multi}[points=1,multiple]{QQ01}
\item* a
\item b
\end{multi}
\begin{multi}[points=1,multiple]{QQ02}
\item* a
\item b
\end{multi}
\end{quiz}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in `moodle.sty`: when a new `quiz` environment is found then a new filehandle for the XML file is created, overwriting the previous file. This can be probably be fixed without too much trouble, however I am not sure what the result should be. Two top-level `<quiz>` elements in one XML file is invalid I think. Another possibility would be a `category` element, some questions, then a new `category` element with some questions, but I don't know if Moodle will accept this (and it is slightly more difficult, because you need to keep track if a quiz is open or not).

Answer (score 3):

I have found a partial solution that can be useful for others.

I use a single `{quiz}` environment which defines the first category, than, when I want to start a new group of questions I do the following

1. add `\end{enumerate}` to close the `{enumerate}` open by `{quiz}` environment
2. add `\setcategory{--my new category--}`
3. add `\subsection*{--my new category--}` to have a title and a correct alignment for the new category
4. add `\begin{enumerate}` to restart an enumerate environment that will be closed by `\end{quiz}`.

Each category will have its numbering.

Answer (score 1):

This unexpected behavior comes from the fact that `moodle` (version 0.5) rewrites over the same XML file each time `\begin{quiz}...\end{quiz}` is found.

The behavior can be fixed by including this code in the preamble after loading `moodle` (still version 0.5)

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\openmoodleout{%
  \immediate\openout\moodle@outfile=\outputfilename\relax
  \writetomoodle{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>}%
  \writetomoodle{<quiz>}%
  \writetomoodle{ }%
}%
\renewenvironment{quiz}[2][]%
{
  \setkeys{moodle}{#1}%
  \@moodle@ifgeneratexml{\setcategory{#2}}{}%
  \subsection*{#2}%
  \begin{enumerate}%
}{
  \end{enumerate}%
}
\AfterEndPreamble{
  \@moodle@ifgeneratexml{\openmoodleout}{}%
}
\AtEndDocument{
  \@moodle@ifgeneratexml{\closemoodleout}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

This bug is addressed in version `0.8` of the `moodle` package.